# PageStorage in Flutter - how does it work?

Tags: flutter

I've seen PageStorage in the documentation. From what I understand its almost like a sharedpreference alternative from the Android world.

How do I use it, and why does it need a Widget in it's implementation?

Comment: Curious, what was the use case that made you go looking and find PageStorage?

Comment: Looks like it has very few uses (5 total): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PageStorage

Comment: I guess I was trying to find the "Flutter" equivalent for SharedPreferences on Android. Rather than implement it myself, thought PageStorage was the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what PageStorage the class is for, but based on your notes, it sounds like you're looking for key value storage.

There is a bug on file about providing a nice plugin for such:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4757

Answer (score 9):

PageStorage is for tracking the state of widgets that may not always be instantiated, for example the position of parallel list views in a pageable view (like when when you have several tabs each with its own list). For something like sharedpreference, you should probably use sharedpreference itself (via a plugin). See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4757 or https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3427.

Answer (score 3):

Below simple example:

`home.dart`

```dart
final pageStorageBucket = PageStorageBucket();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return PageStorage(
    bucket: pageStorageBuket,
    child: Scaffold(
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

`child.dart`

```dart
int storedValue;

@override initState() {
  super.initState();
  storedValue = PageStorage.of(context).readState(context, identifier: 'value');
}

void storeValue(int value) {
  PageStorage.of(context).writeState(context, value, identifier: 'value');
}
```